# Selenium script not working

Tags: selenium, testing

I have created a task as admin and assigned it to writer.As a writer, I need to search the task and click on that particular task edit icon,I am unable to locate the task in the list.In one page 10 task is displayed,task may be in first page or 2nd page.
Can somebody help me with `selenium` code for this.
[image]

**Edit:**

```
List<WebElement> EditButtons = d.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[title='Edit Row']"));
                  String textvalue = d.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='main-content']/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1][contains(text(),'26_Test4')]")).getText();
                   Thread.sleep(3000);
                  System.out.println(textvalue);
                  //Horizontal scroll
                  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)d;
                  js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(2000,0)", "");
                  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) d;
                   //Edit icon path
                  d.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='main-content']/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[12]/i")).click();
```

**Edit**

```
I am getting error 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 3
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
```

**Code**

```
//vertical scroll
          JavascriptExecutor jse3 = (JavascriptExecutor)d;
          jse3.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,  document.body.scrollHeight)");
          Thread.sleep(2000);
          //Zoomout
          JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) d;
          js.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='90%'");
          Thread.sleep(2000);
          System.out.println("Zoomout is successfull");
          List<WebElement> dataTitles = d.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@data-title='Title ']"));
           //System.out.println(dataTitles);
          List<WebElement> editIcons= d.findElements(By.xpath("//td[12]/i"));
           int index=0;
           for(WebElement element : dataTitles) 
           {
           if(element.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("28_res2"))
           {
             break;
           }
            index = index + 1;
        }

           editIcons.get(index).click();
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you have tried for this?

Comment: @AnishPillai I have update the code,please check it.

Comment: Have you checked the xpath for Edit icon using firepath, is it working well on UI? Or there also you have problem in writing the correct xpath?

Comment: @Shoaib Akhtar Yes,I took path using firepath for edit icon and path is correct.It's not recognizing the task in the list, first it has to recognize the task than only it will edit.

Comment: @Akshatha Then your first target is to recognize the 'task', you should inspect 'task', go to firepath, copy paste your code for identifying that element there and then attach that  screenshot here, it might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

See if something like this works for you. I'm finding the list of the data titles using its property `[@data-title='Title ']`. Also I'm assuming that the icons will also have same properties so that you can get a list for these as well.

I'm finding the index at which the exact data is present, so that I can use that index on the icon to click it. If you want to repeat this same logic for multiple pages, then you would need to add all this code in a outer loop which handles the page navigation.

```
List<WebElement> dataTitles = d.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@data-title='Title ']"));
List<WebElement> editIcons= d.findElements(By.xpath("...something..."));

int index=0;
for(WebElement element : dataTitles) {
  if(element.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("26_Test4") {
    break;
  }
index = index + 1;
}

//Click on edit icon at index derived above
editIcons.get(index).click;
```

Comment: I have update the question,Please help me to debug the error.I am getting error in the line 'editIcons.get(index).click();'

Comment: I need to scroll horizontally to get the edit icon, as my horizontal scroll didn't work I used zoom-out to make edit button visible. Still its not clicking on edit icon.